# Strange behavior of MySQL UPDATE query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

When I am executing following query then its not updating views column by 1 instead sometimes its updating it by 2 or 3. Say currently views count is 24 then after executing this query it becomes 26 or sometimes its 27.

```
$views = $views + 1;
$_SQL = '';
$_SQL = 'UPDATE videos SET views = '.$views.' WHERE VideoId= "'.$videoid.'";';
@mysql_query($_SQL);
```

I am not getting why this is happening, am I missing something or the query is executing 2 times automatically? Please help me to figure out the issue.

Thanks

Comment: How many times does this query execute?

Comment: This query executes after whenever page loads. This is basically the view count of a particular video.

Comment: where do you initialize $views variable? do you get any mysql_error? why do you supress errors?

Comment: This views variable is initialized by selecting it from database with `SELECT views FROM videos WHERE videoId=23;` query.

Comment: See my answer, but if you don't want to do that, double-check how it get's the view count.  And double-check the number of times the query executes (put some sort of echo).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the view count, just have the SQL query increment the views,

```
 $_SQL = 'UPDATE videos SET views = views + 1 WHERE VideoId= "'.$videoid.'";'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possibly within a loop? The query is only executing once with this code posted however is this code contained within a while/for loop? If it is check it and then just move the

```
$views = $views + 1;
```

outside the scope of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try printing the value of $views after incrementing it just to see if the problem is in the PHP code or in the SQL query.